# How to install Google Chrome to alternate drive other than C:/ drive?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, ssd, windows-10

*I originally asked on the chrome support forum, but it was marked as a duplicate by a moderator, with the original post being from 2009. The solution being to use System Internal's Junction Utility. Since the functionality of that in windows 10 can not be estimated, I don't want to deal with that if possible.*

I know that the alternate installer used to facilitate that, but it doesn't appear to work anymore. I have been using Chrome portable since I upgraded to an SSD, but I am tired of not getting the latest updates. If you know how to help, I appreciate it. I am using Windows 10.

[My Original Question](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/xJu8dq1Z0WQ)
[The one that Google pointed me to](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/gegy49aC3m0)

If anyone could provide a better answer, it would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The junction trick should work.

Comment: If you read down the Google article, there's another answer using the built in mklink command which was introduced in Vista. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: "I have been using Chrome portable since I upgraded to an SSD, but I am tired of not getting the latest updates." is this from portableapps.com?